# Why is this Stored Procedure Inserting NULL values into the table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to load data (2 columns) from `XML_HOURS_LOAD (columns: code,product)` to a table called `STAGING (columns: code, product)` and am getting null values inserted for both columns:

So I have the following stored procedure:

```
Create or Replace Procedure Cascade_Load (
   p_code in XML_HOURS_LOAD.p_code%TYPE,
   p_product in XML_HOURS_LOAD.p_product%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO STAGING(code, product)
   VALUES(p_code, p_product)

   COMMIT;
END;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, how are you calling it?

Comment: I am just running it (right click, execute). I don't know how i would be able to call the procedure when using a SELECT statement in place of "hard-coded" values. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question of why it's inserting nulls, that is because you aren't providing any values to the procedure parameters when you execute it.

Based on what you stated in the question and your comment above, it seems you are missing some fundamental skills in working with Oracle. The code you wrote is a procedure, not a function, so you can't call it in a `SELECT` statement. A procedure is called inside of a plsql block. Your procedure as written takes two arguments, which you must pass to the procedure call via the calling code. The procedure code you wrote does not look for data from the `XML_HOURS_LOAD` table.

We've all been the new person learning Oracle. You'll want to look at some tutorials to get you started on the fundamentals of pl/sql coding to help clear up the differences between functions and stored procedures and how to use parameter arguments.

From what you wrote in your question, I believe this is the code you want:

```
DECLARE
   p_code IS XML_HOURS_LOAD.code%TYPE,
   p_product IS XML_HOURS_LOAD.product%TYPE;
   CURSOR cXmlHoursLoadCursor IS (SELECT code, product FROM xml_hours_load); --You can add a WHERE condition to this cursor query
BEGIN
    FOR v IN cXmlHoursLoadCursor LOOP
       Cascade_Load(v.code, v.product);
       COMMIT; --I recommend calling commit here instead of inside your stored procedure so that the calling code has control of the transaction state
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I want to do this using PL/SQL . I am not calling it in a select statement, I am trying to set one of the parameters as a select statement. Would i be able to call the procedure like this?  (i.e.) EXEC Cascade_Load (Select code from xml_hours_load, '1') The reason i want to use PL/SQL is because i want to eventually bring in data from various different columns all in one stored procedure.

Comment: what's a good place to really know fundamentals? i've pretty much learned tidbits here and there and getting fundamentals down i think would really help

Comment: I just edited the pl/sql code based on what you wrote in the comment. A good place for Oracle fundamentals is search for books titled something like "PL/SQL Fundamentals". My experience has been that having a good reference book is an excellent investment and beats searching random sites and will be a staple reference guide on your bookshelf. There are also online courses on Lynda.com with exercises. Try to find books that are the same version as your database; you can find really old stuff that is outdated and end up learning old practices.

Comment: Thanks. sorry about my bad fundamentals btw

Comment: @icerabbit No apology needed. We've all been there. Oracle is a monster product and even after 20 years as a DBA and developer I still learn new things about pl/sql. Asking questions and being willing to experiment is a great way to learn new skills.

Comment: Probably a dumb question but do I just add your part of the code into my procedure? Or do I need to run them separately? (thanks in advance)

Comment: The code you gave me won't compile for some reason... figuring out why now..

Comment: I just edited the code. In the declaration, the word in should be is. Try running that, not in your stored procedure, but in sql plus or sql developer or other tool where you can execute code.

Comment: ya i was able to debug haha, eventually figured it out. Thanks a bunch! Do you know of any free online coding courses that may train you on fundamentals?

Comment: I recommend Oracle documentation as a starting point for getting the basics. Specifically the Oracle Concepts Manual and the "2Day..." series. Be prepared to spend some time especially with the Concepts Manual. It's monumental, but complete; for the series start with "2Day Developer".  And use these along side any online tutorial. Oracle publishes these for each version, make sure you get the ones for your version.