# PL/SQL Code returning an error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
   p_code in XML_HOURS_LOAD.code%TYPE,
   p_product in XML_HOURS_LOAD.product%TYPE;
   CURSOR cXmlHoursLoadCursor IS (SELECT code, product FROM xml_hours_load); 
BEGIN
    FOR v IN cXmlHoursLoadCursor LOOP
       Cascade_Load(v.code, v.product);
       COMMIT; 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I am currently encountering the following errors when trying to run the above code, what am I doing wrong? (thanks in advance):

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 29: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN"
>   when expecting one of the following:
>
> constant exception      table long double ref    char time timestamp
>   interval date binary national character    nchar ORA-06550: line 2,
>   column 74: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of
>   the following:
>
> . ( * @ % & - + / at loop mod remainder rem ..     || multiset ORA-06550: line 5, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered
>   the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:
>
> := . ) , @ % default character ORA-06550: line 13, column 4:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of
>   the following:
>
> end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member
>   constructor map
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: Remove in from the declare block. Parameters are declared as name datatype such as p_name varchar2(100);

Comment: You don't declare local variables as IN or OUT - that's only used when declaring procedure/function parameters.

Comment: Your declaration of p_code has a comma  rather than a semi-colon at the end of the line. You don't need the word IN to declare the variables using %TYPE.

Comment: The code you show us is from another topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674120/why-is-this-stored-procedure-inserting-null-values-into-the-table

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 things: 
 
1) You should remove the `in` behind `p_code` and `P_product`. Those are not needed. A whitespace is sufficient, because they are local variables and not input/output parameters to a function/procedure 
2) Behind `XML_HOURS_LOAD.code%TYPE` you have a `,` and there you need a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding [PL/SQL variable anchors](http://www.plsqltutorial.com/plsql-variables/)

> PL/SQL provides you with a very useful feature called variable anchors. It refers to the use of the  %TYPE  keyword to declare a variable with the data type is associated with a column’s data type of a particular column in a table.

This is declare as `[variableName] [dataType];`  for example:

> v_first_name  EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
>
> v_last_name   EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE;

In your case

```
p_code XML_HOURS_LOAD.code%TYPE;
p_product XML_HOURS_LOAD.product%TYPE;
```